# Why addition of discrete probability values for negative binomial does not match to the cumulative probability value, when it matches in Poisson?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

When I manually calculate just negative binomial probability it matches to the value from Excel, or R.
formula : (nCr) *   (p^k) * ( q^(x-k) )

x = 1000 ; k = 4 ;  p = 0.01  ; [ and n = x-1  ; r = k-1 ]

nb_cumul = 0.9899

nb_noncumulative = 0.00007445

If I add non-cumulative negative binomials for k=1, 2, 3, 4 :

0.00000044 + 0.00000440 + 0.00002218 + 0.00007445 = 0.00010147 (from Excel)

why this is different from the cumulative negative binomial probability (0.9899) ?

This kind of addition works well in poisson though !

---

```
##########   in  {R} #############
n = 4    ## num success events
N = 1000   ## total events
mu = 0.01 ## probability of success
dpois(1:n, N*mu)  ## equivalent in Excel =POISSON(n,N*mu,FALSE) [for each value for n = 1:n ; cumulative=FALSE]
[1] 0.0004539993 0.0022699965 0.0075666550 0.0189166374
(dpois(1:n, N*mu))
0.02920729
ppois(n, N*mu)   ## equivalent in Excel =POISSON(n,N*mu,TRUE)  [TRUE => cumulative=TRUE]
0.02925269
### cumulation of dpois(1:n) = ppois(n)  , when rest N and mu are same (almost)

> dnbinom(N, size=1:n, prob=mu) ## equiv of Excel =NEGBINOM.DIST(N-n,n,mu,FALSE) [N-n=num_failure; n=num_success, mu, cumulative=FALSE]
[1] 4.317125e-07 4.321442e-06 2.165042e-05 7.238458e-05
> sum(dnbinom(N, size=1:n, prob=mu))
[1] 9.878816e-05
> pnbinom(N, size=n, prob=mu) ## equiv of Excel =NEGBINOM.DIST(N-n,n,mu,FALSE) [N-n=num_failure; n=num_success, mu, cumulative=TRUE]
[1] 0.99022
```

#### ?  Why the cumulation of dnbinom(1:n) not= pnbinom(n)  , when rest N and mu are same

Comment: `size` is a parameter of the negative binomial distribution, not the value of the r.v.  What you want is `sum(dnbinom(0:n, N, mu))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. However it still does not match the way the two poisson formula work. May be the cumulation for negative-binomial works some other way !

Answer (score 2):

It's primarily because you omitted the case where $x=0$. Also (I'm not sure I follow everything you are doing) you seem to be confusing the *binomial* and the *negative* binomial distributions. The binomial is for the number of successes in a given number of trials, and negative binomial is for the number of trials encountered before a given number of successes is observed.

Comment: I guess, in either case we can get a probability value for the number of success to occur (like in excel : i can use N-n as number of failures).